Infinite dust-plane solution in general relativity
In both Newtonian gravity and General Relativity, an initially static universe with uniform dust collapses in a finite time into a singularity. In fact, Newton and GR predict the same speed of collapse and are indistinguishable for slow-moving observers.
What about an infinite dust plane? It would be like a domain wall but made out of dust instead having a $p=-2/3\rho$ tension. Would it collapse?
It does not seem to collapse under Newtonian gravity. A V-shaped $\phi = k |z|$ solves Poissons equation for an x-y plane of uniform mass/area and $k=2\pi G \rho$. Since there are no force (gradients) in the x or y direction, the plane will not collapse. I don't see a reason why it would collapse under GR.
A plane is an unstable equilibrium in Newtonian gravity in that it will tend to break up into an irregular grid of "galaxies and clusters" if perturbed. Presumably, in GR this is also the case.
In Newtonian gravity, the gravity is constant and does not decrease with distance. But I think that GR is different. Presumably the spacetime outside of the plane is flat (since Newtonian physics predicts no tidal forces). In which case the problem becomes computing accelerations in Rindler coordinates and the result is that the gravity drops off as $g =  \frac {g_0} {1+|z g_0 /c^2|}$, where $z$ is (I think) the proper distance measured by static ropes. But is my assumption of flat space outside the plane correct?

In Newtonian gravity "an initially static universe with uniform dust collapses in a finite time into a singularity". In fact, the field is not well defined without breaking the symmetry with arbitrary boundary conditions.

@PatoGalmarini: For the most symmetrical boundary conditions (as in no "xy" or other non-linear term with zero Laplacian), it does not matter if you are at the "center" (where the solution has zero gravity) or not. You experience the same collapse the same way.

That does not make any sense to me, Newtonian gravity simply fails or needs some extra assumptions for an infinite universe with a uniform dust.  Like with Norton's dome. You are minimizing a big issue related to the limits of theories.

spacetime is not flat outside the plane, at least the gtt is a function of the height in both possible relativistic solutions of the problem, see here and the links therein

@PatoGalmarini: Maybe it's better to define it as the limit of larger and lager spherical clouds of dust rather than just say "infinite" initially at rest. They collapse equally in all directions.
